# sort an array but exclude certain array elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an array that contain

```
var arr = [{
    firstName: 'Jane',
    lastName:'Doe',
    age:19,
    isActive: true
},
{
    firstName: 'Wane',
    lastName:'Doe',
    age:21,
    isActive: false
},
{
    firstName: 'Kane',
    lastName:'Doe',
    age:23,
    isActive: false
},
{
    firstName: 'Mane',
    lastName:'Doe',
    age:25,
    isActive: true
}]
```

The sorting function looks like

```
const sortedRows = (rows: any) => {
            let order === 'asc'; // this is static for the time being
            return [...rows].sort((a, b) => {
                const aData = a['firstName'] === null ? '' : a['firstName'];
                const bData = b['firstName'] === null ? '' : b['firstName'];

                if (order === 'asc') {
                    return aData > bData ? 1 : -1;
                }
                return bData > aData ? 1 : -1;
            });
};
```

The sorting works as expected but I would like to align `isActive:false` elements at the end of the sorted rows.

So the final result should be like

```
[
  {
    "firstName": "Jane",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "age": 19,
    "isActive": true
  },
  
  {
    "firstName": "Mane",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "age": 25,
    "isActive": true
  },
  // listing all isActive:false at the end
  {
    "firstName": "Kane",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "age": 23,
    "isActive": false
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Wane",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "age": 21,
    "isActive": false
  }
]
```

Comment: So compare the two items regarding isActive first, and only if they both have the same value, continue with the rest of the comparison logic.

Comment: Either sort two times, which would be the easiest but not the most optimal. Otherwise check on isActive first.

Comment: Worth pointing out `return aData > bData ? 1 : -1;`. Is also wrong and can fail.  Look at @Nina answer with `localeCompare` on a better way to sort strings.

Answer (score 2):

You could sort by boolean first and the by `firstName` with a default in a single function.

```js
const
    array = [{ firstName: 'Jane', lastName:'Doe', age:19, isActive: true }, { firstName: 'Wane', lastName:'Doe', age:21, isActive: false }, { firstName: 'Kane', lastName:'Doe', age:23, isActive: false }, { firstName: 'Mane', lastName:'Doe', age:25, isActive: true }];


array.sort((a, b) => b.isActive - a.isActive || (a.firstName || '').localeCompare(b.firstName || ''));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add to sorting that the one with the "false" (if the other is true) is always "lower"

```js
var arr = [{
    firstName: 'Jane',
    lastName:'Doe',
    age:19,
    isActive: true
},
{
    firstName: 'Wane',
    lastName:'Doe',
    age:21,
    isActive: false
},
{
    firstName: 'Kane',
    lastName:'Doe',
    age:23,
    isActive: false
},
{
    firstName: 'Mane',
    lastName:'Doe',
    age:25,
    isActive: true
}]

const sortedRows = (rows) => {
            let order = 'asc'; // this is static for the time being
            return [...rows].sort((a, b) => {
                const aData = a['firstName'] === null ? '' : a['firstName'];
                const bData = b['firstName'] === null ? '' : b['firstName'];
                
                if (a?.isActive === false && b?.isActive === true) {
                  return 1;
                }

                if (a?.isActive === true && b?.isActive === false) {
                  return -1;
                }


                if (order === 'asc') {
                    return aData > bData ? 1 : -1;
                }
                return bData > aData ? 1 : -1;
            });
};

const sorted = sortedRows(arr);
console.log(sorted);
```